# Blender 3.1.2 joined (internal) objects rotate at different rates when animation applied to whole

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

I have a gear assembly made up of a joined gear wheel, hub, and spokes. The gear assembly is parented to a timing belt gear which rotates 12 times over 360 frames i.e. the belt gear goes from 0 to 4320 degrees rotation with a key frame at 1 and 361 and linear interpolation applied. What happens is the gear wheel does rotate with the parent belt gear but the spokes and hub rotate in the opposite direction at a faster rate.  The whole assembly should obviously rotate in unison with the parent belt gear as one would expect and not internal parts separately. What am I doing wrong or is this a Blender bug?

Here is a link to a file that shows the problem:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e14913ff583449c2ec6a8f028b83890720220624043100/57a5e7357ee7fe48bbbfbbcff74263b720220624043133/77b316

[image]

Comment: this is really weird. How did you create that animation? Did the gear1.001 formerly consists of 3 objects which you animated seperatedly? i never saw something like this....

Comment: i never saw one object rotating in different directions as your did. If i join two objects -> they rotate the same....i am really surprised and curious what the experts will say to this -> looks like i will learn something new today ;)

Comment: Originally the gear shape was created in Adobe Illustrator and imported as SVG into Blender and extruded. The other pieces are Blender objects. All were aligned to the 3D cursor at World Origin and position adjusted to final configuration. I parented the gear assembly to the smaller belt drive gear then rotated all 90 degrees perpendicular to the grid floor.  I then animated the belt drive gear to rotate twelve times over 360 frames.  If you zoom out you will see two other similar gears created entirely in Blender that work correctly.  I can't figure it out.

Comment: And oddly, even when you apply Union booleans to all the parts and they clearly appear to be a single mesh when selected and moved (and also look fused in wireframe mode) the gear wheel rotates separately and in the opposite direction of the hub and spokes.

Comment: as i said - i never saw something like that and wonder why nobody can help here....